# Why the 'BINARY' in a SELECT statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In a `Vote` model, there is a validation:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :topic_id, :scope => [:user_id]
```

It is translated to the following SQL in development log:

```
SELECT 1 AS one FROM `votes` WHERE (`votes`.`topic_id` = BINARY 2 AND `votes`.`user_id` = 1) LIMIT 1
```

Where there is a `BINARY` in front of 2 (topic_id)? And, what does it mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is an efficient way of comparing byte to byte instead of character to character

example

Suppose if your have a database table called `products` record which has `vin_number` (**some  column name**) with record with value of `vin_number` say `123456`

Now If you ran the this

```
select * from products where vin= '123456'
```

and

```
select * from products where vin = '123456 '
```

Both will result the same result

Notice the space in the second select

But with binary the comparison

```
select * from products where vin= BINARY '123456'
```

or

```
select * from producst where vin = BINARY '123456 '
```

A byte by byte match is done as against character to character

so the first one would result in `valid` result

and

the second one would **no  result**

Here the [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html) that will further help you on this

Comment: Ooops, broken link